# Clean up WhatsApp cache

Tags: apps, whatsapp, 8.1-update-1

Is there any way to clean up the cache used by WhatsApp other than reinstalling? Because lots of audio messages and voice recordings made my WhatsApp Data size much bigger (Around 700 MB).

Comment: Go to files at your phone,you will get WhatsApp media place and can delete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only option I found so far is, make at least 300 MB of free storage and perform whatsapp's Backup to SD. This will clean up the cache stored in the phone memory.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately there is no Windows Phone settings menu to delete the cache of 3rd party apps. You could try to delete individual (voice) messages, but of course that might be a lot of work.

The easiest way at the moment would be a reinstall.

Also, you should consider contacting WhatsApp directly about this issue - for them it should be easy to offer a appropriate function.

Comment: Hope you know how hard it is...

Comment: I can imagine - though you should be able to restore the backup, right?

Answer (score 2):

Other than reinstalling you can try the option to clear chat history for groups and you can delete the individual chat messages. I guess this is the easiest way in the case of whatsapp.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no way through which one can clear Windows Phone cache of 3rd party apps. This can be done by deleting individual messages but it will take a lots of time.

The only way is that reinstall whatsApp. reinstalling will clear a lots of space not full.

Hope this will help you out!! :)

Answer (score -1):

Install clean master. And go to advance cleaning. You can delete all the cache data in one go, even for other apps.

Comment: can you add a link to the app you are referring to?

Comment: I cnt find the app called clean master, its only storage clean tats on d options wit other types.. I'm really frustrated wit dis space buildup, over 1gig of it.. I use a 730, any help pls..

Answer (score -1):

Go to WhatsApp chat delete the chat data is reduced and delete daily backup also.

Comment: Its' not clear from your answer as to *how* to do this?